# multiple arity in defmacro of clojure

Tags: macros, clojure

I encountered a strange problem relating to defmacro in Clojure, I have code like

```
(defmacro ttt
  ([] (ttt 1))
  ([a] (ttt a 2))
  ([a b] (ttt a b 3))
  ([a b c] `(println ~a ~b ~c)))
```

and I run with `(ttt)`, it suppose to become `(println 1 2 3)`, and print "1 2 3", but what I got is

```
ArityException Wrong number of args (-1) passed to: t1$ttt clojure.lang.Compiler.macroexpand1 (Compiler.java:6473)
```

after some investigation, I understand I should write

```
(defmacro ttt
  ([] `(ttt 1))
  ([a] `(ttt ~a 2))
  ([a b] `(ttt ~a ~b 3))
  ([a b c] `(println ~a ~b ~c)))
```

but why the first version failed? and `args` is too strange to understand, where `-1` comes from?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Macros have two hidden arguments

Macros have two hidden arguments `&form` and `&env` that provide additional information about invocation and bindings that are the cause of the arity exception here.  To refer to other arity versions within the same macro, use quasi-quote expansion.

```
(defmacro baz
  ([] `(baz 1))
  ([a] `(baz ~a 2))
  ([a b] `(baz ~a ~b 3))
  ([a b c] `(println ~a ~b ~c)))

user=> (macroexpand-1 '(baz))
(clojure.core/println 1 2 3)

user=> (baz)
1 2 3
nil
```

### Arity exception messages subtract the hidden arguments from the count

The reason you get the (-1) arity exception is because the compiler subtracts these two hidden arguments when generating the error message for the general macro usage. The true message here for your first version of `ttt` would be "Wrong number of args (1)" because you supplied one argument `a` but the two additional hidden arguments were not provided by self-invocation.

### Multi-arity macros not common in the wild

In practice, I suggest avoiding multi-arity macros altogether. Instead, consider a helper function to do most of the work on behalf of the macro. Indeed, this is often a good practice for other macros as well.

```
(defn- bar
  ([] (bar 1))
  ([a] (bar a 2))
  ([a b] (bar a b 3))
  ([a b c] `(println ~a ~b ~c)))


(defmacro foo [& args] (apply bar args))

user=> (macroexpand-1 '(foo))
(clojure.core/println 1 2 3)

user=> (foo)
1 2 3
nil
```

### Macro expansion is recursive

Your second `ttt` version works as well due to the recursive nature of macro-expansion

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(ttt))
(user/ttt 1)
user=> (macroexpand-1 *1)
(user/ttt 1 2)
user=> (macroexpand-1 *1)
(usr/ttt 1 2 3)
user=> (macroexpand-1 *1)
(clojure.core/println 1 2 3)
```

So,

```
user=> (macroexpand '(ttt))
(clojure.core/println 1 2 3)
```

Comment: Well, then. What docs described that two hidden args? And what info they contain?

Comment: Nitpick about *"Macroexpansion is recursive"*: `macroexpand` computes a fixpoint by repeatedly calling `macroexpand-1`, but neither `macroexpand` nor `macroexpand-1` call themselves recursively (except if your macro does). See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/39943529/124319

Comment: I'm not understanding the subtlety you are relaying, but `macroexpand`  _does_ indeed call itself in a recursive manner. Perhaps you are saying that `macroexpand` does _not_ descend into subforms? This is true, but of course the compiler then _does_, which would then trigger fresh calls to macroexpand as needed.

Comment: Explicitly passing the hidden arguments works, but you're not supposed to do that, because it relies on an implementation detail. The quasi-quote way is the only way. ([source](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-2136?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=50517#comment-50517))

Answer (score 1):

When Clojure processes definition of `ttt` macro, it isn't created yet and cannot be used for source code transformation inside the macrodefinition. For compiler, your macro is something like (well, not really, but it is a good example):

```
(defmacro ttt0 []       (ttt1 1))
(defmacro ttt1 [a]      (ttt2 a 2))
(defmacro ttt2 [a b]    (ttt3 a b 3))
(defmacro ttt3 [a b c] `(println ~a ~b ~c))
```

Try to evaluate denition of `ttt0`, you will get:

> CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: ttt1 in this context

So, when Clojure processes definition of a macro, **it must expand macros in unquoted parts of the definition**, as for any other part of code. It fails with `ttt1`, and *must* fail in your case. My guess is that it is something like a bug. It is difficult to say why you get `-1`, I think it has to do with internal machinery of the language realization.

Here we can see difference between macros and functions: macros work on any input code to transform it immediately, while a function must be called and everything is always defined and ready for it:

```
user> (defn ttt
        ([] (ttt 1))
        ([a] (ttt a 2))
        ([a b] (ttt a b 3))
        ([a b c] :works!))
;; => #'user/ttt
user> (ttt)
;; => :works!
```

Here calls of `ttt` are just instructions, they will be executed when `ttt` is called.

Comment: I'm afraid the gist of this answer is wrong. It is helpful to think of macros as simply functions that run at compile time. They work the same way in most instances, just at different times. Indeed you may have a recursive macro, or even a multiple arity one though rare. This multiple arity example fails because Clojure inserts two hidden arguments for macros which are not being provided during internal invocation.