# "Wrong number of args (-1) passed to: core/blahblah" in Clojure

Tags: clojure, macros

Can someone explain me how arguments count can be less then 0? This is my code, JIC. But I don't really care why it is not working - I just want to know how it is even theoretically possible to get less then 0 arguments.

```
(defmacro infix
  [[x op & r]]
    (if-not (empty? r)
      (if (or (= op "*") (= op "/"))
        (infix (conj (rest r) (list op x (first r))))
        (list op x (infix r)))
      x))

(infix (1 + 2))
```

Comment: Check out A. Webb's answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25569059